# Reference request for Loci/Transformations in the Complex Plane

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, soft-question

I'd like to apologize in advance for what may be considered a really LQ, question but it's something I really need answered. I'm currently taking A-level Further maths in the UK, which is a qualification that those who show somewhat of a mathematical aptitude take.

So, I've reached a topic in my mathematical studies which I really do not like. The forefront reason as to why I really dislike it, is because I don't actually understand it and I'm just applying recipes without any thought which I hate doing. That topic is **Loci in the Complex Plane** and **Transformations of the Complex Plane**.

So, I've moaned a lot, but what I'd really like for someone to do is to tell me the requisite topics to study. I'm not very strong in geometry and have a feeling this requires knowledge of advanced geometric topics. Also, I'd like to ask what is the correlation between the Mobius transformation and normal transformations in the Complex plane?

Thanks in advance

Comment: For what it's worth, this is a perfectly fine question. Welcome.

Comment: I recommend you have a look at the introductory chapters of [Visual Complex Analysis](http://www.amazon.in/Visual-Complex-Analysis-Tristan-Needham/dp/0198534469)